# Organize a linkedlist into an array of linkedlist in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I am writing a method that takes a function that takes a root of a linked list and the number of vertices in a graph and organizes the linked list into an array of linked list based on the first vertex of an edge struct, for example, in a struct where an node Edge has firVertex = 1, sndVertex = 2, and weight = 2, it would be sorted into the first element of an array. and another node Edge that has another firVertex = 1 would be appended onto the previous one, and etc. My code compiles but it's not exactly doing what I want. Please help.

Comment: Look like you are returning a pointer to local variable.

Comment: I'm really new to programming in general and C++, could you give me a suggestion as to what to fix?

Comment: Return *std::vector<Edge*>* if this is C++.

Comment: I feel that there are other problems in your code, you should learn more about memory management in C first, not just trying to do fix, you can't write C code without knowning that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues in your code.

While assigning the `newNode` to the elements of array list it should be

```
arrayList[j]= newNode; //not 'i' since i=numberVertices always....
```

When you are finding a `firVertex` matching the `j`, you are creating a temporary pointer which points to the current node. Then you are doing this:

```
newNode -> next = NULL;
```

It actually changes the `next` of the node in the given list to `NULL`, thus making the `current->next` as `NULL` and your code won't process the whole list. It should be instead as follows:

```
Edge* newNode = new Edge(current);//create a copy of the 'current' node..
newNode -> next = NULL;//now make the 'next' of this node NULL..
```

The above code prevents the list from any modifications. I also assume there is a constructor for `Edge`, which takes another `Edge` pointer as argument.

As you specified in the question, if you have two `Edge` nodes with same `firVertex`, you wanted to append them on the same list. But your code merely over-writes the previous node. 
To prevent that, it can be written as follows:

```
Edge* newNode = new Edge(current);
newNode -> next = NULL;
Edge* tmp = arrayList[j];
if(tmp==NULL)//then this is the first node..
{
     arrayList[j] = new Edge(current);
     arrayList[j]->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    while(tmp->next!=NULL)//go to the end of the list...
      tmp = tmp->next;
   tmp->next = new Edge(current);//create a copy of the 'current' node...
   tmp->next->next=NULL;//make the next of this new node NULL...
}
```

Hope this helps...and I strongly feel that you need to learn more about pointers and then start coding.